# .net core Initializing objects for 24hrs

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions

I created a .net azure Http function and in that I need to reuse the instantiated class object for 24hrs without any interruption. for every single http request I can't instantiate due to performance. could someone help me on how to create solution for this.
thanks,

Comment: So, why do you use Azure Function then?

Comment: Don't use a function then. By their very nature serverless APIs are stateless. That's not an Azure limitation, all serverless services work that way

Comment: Why not cache whatever that object holds and load it from your API methods? Or store its final form in a database? Azure offers [Durable Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=csharp) that abstract this up to a point.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, I will load on cache or store in the db